# Regex: Getting middle digits from another digit

Tags: regex

My string (a line, actually) looks like this:

```
abc bsdb kms 324 kdf 12345678
```

I want to get a 3rd to 5th number from the number at the end of the line. It's always at the end of the line and it has fixed number of 8 digits.

Desired result:

```
345
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex to use:

```
\b\d{2}(\d{3})\d{3}$
```

Group 1 will hold the `345` value.

To be able to capture values at the end of lines, just use multiline option.

See [(updated) demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP7kI3/3)

Comment: dominated by secs.. :( .. plus from me.. also.. you dont need to match starting two digits and word boundary.. since format is fixed here.. :)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to strictly follow the format in the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
(\d{3})\d{3}$
```

and extract the required group by `$1` or `\1`

Explanation:

- match six digits from the end `$` and capture first three (since your length is fixed to 8 it matches middle 3 numbers)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL5cP8/1)